# Who is this man changing the name of Little Dice to Li'll Z?

Tags: character, city-of-god

In the movie City of God, who was the man that Changes the name of Li'll Dice to Li'll Z?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer satisfy you? If not, what sort of information would you like to see?

Comment: Zé Pequeno is short for Little José, portuguese version of Joseph. Li'll Zé = Small Joseph.

Answer (score 2):

He doesn't appear to have a name. Interestingly, TV Tropes lists this as a [**meaningful rename** trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MeaningfulRename):

> The name is the thing, and the true name is the true thing — so if the
> name changes...
>
> Some names have obvious meanings but often, this is
> done when it is not the original name for the person, place or object,
> but rather, a new one given by someone or assumed.

On City of God they say:

> In City of God, Lil Dice gets the new name Lil Ze from a religious
> practitioner, who states his new name will change his fate.

This is discussed in a 2004 article I found, which includes quotes from an [interview](http://www.nitrateonline.com/2004/fcityofgod.html) with the film's director Fernando Meirelles:

> City of God also drapes itself in layers of subplot, resulting in a
> complex web of detail that can only be fully absorbed through repeated
> viewings.  One surreal scene, for instance, shows Lil’ Ze’s ritual
> transformation from child to man, as he visits a sinister witch
> doctor’s candle-lit cathedral.  “This amulet is your protector,” the
> elder explains, placing a necklace around the killer’s neck. Many
> viewers might easily miss the significance of this witch doctor’s
> insistence that Lil’ Ze not fornicate while wearing the amulet. Watch
> City of God a second time, however, it becomes clear that the hood’s
> violation of this command is the catalyst for his undoing.
>
> “The scene with the witch doctor,” explains Meirelles, “comes from a
> religion brought to Brazil from Africa, called Candonble, that
> incorporates a lot of saints and entities, like gods that protect the
> sea and the winds. Different archetypes called orixas.  In this scene,
> a very mean orixa – presented through the witch doctor - gives Lil’
> Ze’ his power. But he is told that he can’t screw anybody with that
> amulet on. Later he rapes a girl. We don’t see the rape actually
> happen. Instead, there are three seconds showing only the amulet.”

So the man in the scene is some type of **witch doctor** although his exact name isn't revealed.